# "does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard." What am i doing wrong in this case?

Tags: php, laravel, psr-4

`Class Database\Factories\Tasks\UserFactory located in ./database/factories/tasks/UserFactory.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.`

This is my php file:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories\Tasks;

use App\Models\Tasks\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
  ...
}
```

Located in: `database/factories/tasks/`

Can someone explain me why this doesnt comply with psr-4 autoloading standard?

Answer (score 4):

PSR-4 Autoload Standard is case sensitive. So If your Namespace starts with an Uppercase, your Folder name should do this also.

In your example, the directory should be Database/Factories/Tasks.

Comment: Are you sure? If i remove the `tasks` folder it just works fine, for example, i change the namespace to `Database\Factories\UserFactory.php` and the folder still is lowercase `database/factories/UserFactory.php` (works ok, no errors), it only happens if i add another folder to the `factories` folder, so it doesnt make sense.

Comment: What is your PSR-4 Configuration in your composer.json?

Have a look at https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php#L188

There is the comparison. Based on your answer i assume that Database\Factories is directly mapped to the path. But Task is then the additional folder which needs to be Upper Case for the first Letter.

Comment: @JoãoHamerski Case insensitivity may be related to the os you are using. Windows does not care whilst a UNIX based system does to the very last letter

Comment: I was able to resolve the same problem by renaming the child directories only. E.g. `database/Factories/Tasks`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in your composer.json file from
this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "Database/Factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "Database/Seeders/"
    }
},
```

to

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "Database/Factories/Task",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "Database/Seeders/"
    }
},
```